# Push notification registration token get deleted after 45 days

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, mobilepush

As per the below screen shot, connection token gets deleted after 45 days. So mobile user need to reinstall the application after every 45 days period. Any work around is there so that no reinstallation is required after 45 days.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reinstallation is not required.  The SDK automatically handles re-registration of the connection token on app launch.